# Why some functions don't involve kernel?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, system, posix

In *Advanced Programing in the UNIX Environment 2nd Edition, chapter 01, section 11*, there is a sentence:

> For example, the printf function may use the write system call to output a string,
>   but the strcpy (copy a string) and atoi (convert ASCII to integer) functions don't
>   involve the kernel at all.

What I don't understand is that, why it is possible that there is no involvement of kernel at all. Aren't all routines require kernel support?

Also, I may figure out that `atoi` only requires CPU computation. But as `strcpy` need the memory operation, why it doesn't involve kernel support either?

Generally, how can I recognize that a function doesn't involve the kernel?

Comment: The kernel generally only gets involved when a program wants to communicate outside of itself, or reconfigure the system.  For example, accessing already allocated memory does not tend to require (explicit) involvement of the kernel, however a new memory allocation may, if it cannot be satisfied from a pool already held within the program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What I don't understand is that, why it is possible that there is no involvement of kernel at all. Aren't all routines require kernel support?

At the *very* lowest level, yes, because a process wouldn't even exist without the kernel starting it, but that doesn't mean the kernel is involved in every operation.  You wouldn't exist without your parents, but that doesn't mean you can't get dressed "without the involvement of your parents".

If you write a simple function in C that simply dereferences its argument, that is a routine, and it doesn't require support from the kernel:

```
int func(int* p) { return *p; }
```

Some library functions, such as `atoi` and `strcpy` are like this, they don't invoke any system calls to make use of services provided by the kernel.

> Also, I may figure out that `atoi` only requires CPU computation. But as `strcpy` need the memory operation, why it doesn't involve kernel support either?

The kernel isn't used to copy bytes from one place to another within the same address space.  The virtual memory subsystem might be involved at a very low level, to map virtual addresses to physical addresses, but that's true for almost **every** operation, even (if it's not in a register) reading or setting the value of an `int`!

Anyway, `atoi` has to read memory, why do you not consider that to "need the memory operation" too?

> Generally, how can I recognize that a function doesn't involve the kernel?

You can't in general, without reading the source of the function.  However, if a function can be implemented in pure C, without interacting with hardware or services provided by the kernel (such as forking new processes, or communicating with other processes) then it's likely it doesn't use system calls.  Some operating systems provide ways to find out which system calls a process uses, e.g. the `strace` utility, which will tell you whenever a process invokes a system call.  You can also trace the process or intercept system calls by interposition, but that is quite complicated and out of scope for this answer.

Comment: Thanks for the details! So if I know that a C function contains NO call to system call(in a transitive sense) and no embeded ASM, then it doesn't involve kernel?

Comment: Yes. Even if it contains embedded ASM it might not involve the kernel either, unless the ASM uses a system call.

Answer (score 5):

It seems to mean that the function doesn't lead to system calls by saying 'not involve kernel", from the context of that sentence.

Comment: So *involve the kernel* means that these *system calls* in Section 2?

Comment: i don't have that book by hand so not sure what section 2 is... but generally system call is the way user program interact with kernel.